# Is there a name for this type of Turing machine?

Tags: turing-machines

I'm considering turing machines with tape alphabet equal to $\{0,1\}$ and the blank symbol equal to $0$. Is there a name for this type of Turing machines? Isn't this type the one computers are based on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That would be a **Turing machine with a binary tape alphabet**. The term **binary Turing machine** also seems to be common enough (a [Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q="binary+Turing+machine") gives just under 1000 results for the term).

As David Richerby pointed out in the other answer, though, Turing machines are *not* what computers are based on. Rather, (modern) computers are based on *register machines* ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Register_machine)). What we do have is an [equivalence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_completeness) between the two computation models.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure about a name, but real computers aren't based on Turing machines at all.